# Is the word 'statement' in 'statement block' redundant?

Tags: syntax

Is the word 'statement' in 'statement block' redundant?

In other words is a block in a program composed, by definition, of statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many languages don't have statements, only expressions. Ruby, for example, doesn't have statements, but it does have blocks:

```
begin
  some_expression
  some_other_expression
  a_third_expression
end
```

Since Ruby doesn't have statements, which means everything is an expression, which means everything has a value, obviously blocks are expressions and have values, too:

```
foo = begin
  some_expression
  some_other_expression
  a_third_expression
end
```

There are no statements in this Ruby block, since there are no statements in Ruby, period.

[**Note**: Ruby has a construct called *block*, which is *not* the kind of block you are asking about. It is a syntactically light-weight anonymous first-class procedure. The word "block" is also sometimes used for "documentation blocks" or "comment blocks", again, these are not the kinds of "block" you are asking about.]

Answer (score 3):

No.  A program's text can contain "comment" or "documentation" blocks as well, and certain languages might have "data structure" blocks, like baked-in XML or JSON.